# Add DOM element to onclick function

Tags: javascript

I want to add a DOM element to a HTML onclick function but I don't know how. Maybe the question is more clear when I show you some code:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
var element2 = document.createElement('div');

element1.setAttribute('onclick','function('+element2+')');
```

I know you should start with

```
onclick="function(this...)"
```

and navigate like this to the element I want but I wonder if it is possible in a way to do this like mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt functionality that maps an element to a string. If you are looking for a way to pass the element to the handler, try:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
var element2 = document.createElement('div');

element1.addEventListener('onclick',(function(element2){return function(){/* do something with element2 here*/})(element2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your aiming at here but it's unnecessary to do what your doing...

This is the link or whatever your intending to click...

```
var someLink = document.getElementById('#some-link');
```

When you click it you can do something with some divs...

```
someLink.onclick = function() {

  var element1 = document.createElement('div');
  var element2 = document.createElement('div');

  // Do something with element1 or element2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
    $(someElement).click(function(){
       var element1 = document.createElement('div');
       var element2 = document.createElement('div');

       // Do something here
    });
```